# Maven javafx plugin creating duplicate dependencies

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm trying to create a JavaFX application using maven but it seems that the JavaFX plugin is creating duplicate dependencies. This is what gets spit out during mvn javafx:run

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:win -> duplicate declaration of version 17.0.0.1 @ line 129, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:win -> duplicate declaration of version 17.0.0.1 @ line 141, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:win -> duplicate declaration of version 17.0.0.1 @ line 153, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:win -> duplicate declaration of version 17.0.0.1 @ line 165, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:win -> duplicate declaration of version 17.0.0.1 @ line 189, column 17
```

Whereas in my pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-ALPHA</version>
    <name>xxx-DEV-1</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>charm-glisten</id>
            <name>charm-glisten Repository</name>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>me.xxx.xxx.xxx</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I clearly did not list any of these dependencies twice. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the module-info:

```
module  me.xxx.xxx{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;


    exports me.xxx.xxx;
}
```

Comment: In Idea, I created a new project using the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), selecting openjfx 17.0.1. I then replaced the pom.xml file generated by the wizard with the pom.xml you provided (without any change) and resynched the maven project with the idea project. It then built and ran fine both mvn:install and the Idea run icon (arrow in the gutter as per Idea New JavaFX project instructions). I ran some dependency analysis on the resultant project and there were no issues. Testing was done on OS X 11.

Comment: I also tried this using the mvn javafx:run command and it worked fine for me with no warnings or issues.  For it to work, I needed to update the dependency for the plugin from 0.0.7 to 0.0.8 due to an unrelated permissions incompatibility between version 0.0.7 of the plugin and the maven setup used in Idea.  Otherwise, the setup was the same as the previous comment.

Comment: According to its [documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin), the openjfx maven plugin uses the maven toolchains system to find the JDK to use.

Comment: If you want to execute a run command using `mvn javafx:run` (rather than just directly running the resultant jar off the module path using the `java` command), then check that your maven is installed and JAVA_HOME configured as per [maven installation instructions](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) and (if necessary) [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-toolchains-plugin/toolchains/jdk.html) are configured for override (only if you need to override or explictly specify the java home or jdk to use).  Remove old JDKs like JDK 8 from your system.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem. Could you try adding your "openjfx excludes" to controlsfx too? It was necessary in my case.

Comment: I added the exclusions field to all other dependencies, still getting multiple duplicates :/

Comment: Just in order to avoid misunderstandings. In general it should not be necessary at all to provide these exclusion. My case with controlsfx was just a little bit special and therefore I thought it might help in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that maven was using multiple JDKs to compile the source.

Removing old JDK 8 fixed the issue